# Writing a long dataframe to SQL

Tags: python, sql, database, dataframe, wkt

I have a dataframe (consisting of 8 columns) with 338 rows. One of these columns has a wkt format (i.e. it contains a representation of a MultiPolygon). I'm trying to write my dataframe to SQL with the following code:

```
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        'mysql+pymysql://root:maria@localhost:3306/topology?unix_socket=/data/mysql/mysql.sock', pool_recycle=3600)
    #After researching, I found that if I added pool_recycle=3600, it would prevent a SQL timeout
    
    #Since the Polygon is more than some letters, it is necessary to specify the length: 
    datatype={
        "coordinates": LONGTEXT
    }
    
    #Write to Database:
    dataframe.to_sql(
        name='Federal_Info',
        con=engine,
        index=False,
        dtype=datatype,
        if_exists='replace')
    
    #The next two lines of code convert the wkt format to a geom type
    engine.execute('''ALTER TABLE `topology`.`Federal_Info`
                   ADD COLUMN `geom` Polygon;''')
    
    engine.execute('''UPDATE `topology`.`Federal_Info`
                   SET geom =  ST_GeomFromText(coordinates) ;''')
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 713, in _write_bytes
    self._sock.sendall(data)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

...
 File "/home/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 718, in _write_bytes
    "MySQL server has gone away (%r)" % (e,))
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))")
```

Is there anyway to solve this issue? The wkt column is quite a large piece of text.

---

What I tried:

I tried to add a pool_recycle parameter to my sql create engine function but that didn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: It's possible that the dataframe is larger than MySQL's max_allowed_packet. Have you tried using the `chunksize` parameter to `to_sql` to make it write fewer rows at once?

Comment: @NickODell I also did try that but it seemed to give the same error: `(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)`. It's weird, I didn't have this error while uploading Polygons to the table but obviously MultiPolygons seems to fail.

Comment: How much memory does each column take? (You can find this information by running `print(dataframe.memory_usage(deep=True))`

Comment: @NickODell it is quite large, as I mentioned since I have a MultiPolygon. `coordinates 651198910` is the largest column (containing the multipolygon). Should I maybe iterate through my dataframe and upload every row to the sql while creating a new connection?

Comment: 1) That's what chunksize does, if you set it to 1. It inserts the dataframe one row at a time. Have you tried a chunksize of 1? 2) If coordinates is 621 MB, that suggests each row is approximately 1.8 MB. Inserting single rows might not be enough - you may also have to raise the [max_allowed_packet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) setting. The default depends on the MySQL version. What version of MySQL server are you using?

Comment: @NickODell thanks for the feedback, yes, the row is in fact very large. Even using a chunksize of 1 fails. I'm using MariaDB and my version is: 10.1.48-MariaDB - MariaDB Server. After looking online, it seems that I can change the max_allowed_pocket in one of two ways. 1) Go to the /etc/my.cnf (since I am using RHEL 7) file and add the following line: `max_allowed_packet=32M` or 2) run the following command in CLI: `mysql --max_allowed_packet=32M`? Is that correct?

Comment: Method 1 will work. You'll also need to restart MySQL. Method 2 will not work, as it only sets a per-session value.